# What would cause multiple instances of singleton in DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, loadlibrary, cl

I am aware that this question has been asked and answered in different forms over the years, but I find the previous Q&As about it too tied to specific examples and not providing me with a full understanding of why, and in what scenarios, dlls can produce multiple instances of the same  singleton. I am struggling to come up with a minimal reproducible example myself.

Given a singleton in the rough form:

```
class Singleton
{
private:
    static Singleton* singleton;
public:
    Singelton(); // 
    ~Singleton(); // Not shown for brevity.
    static Singelton* getSingleton();
};

Singleton* Singleton::getSingleton()
{
    if (!singleton)
    {
        singleton= new Singleton;
    }

    return singleton;
}
```

This is compiled in to a dll (I'll call is `SingletonAndOtherStuff.dll`) which is intended for loading via `LoadLibrary` by other apps.

This next bit is where I start to get confused.

Within a separate primary app (I'll call it `app.exe`), `SingletonAndOtherStuff.dll` is loaded via `LoadLibrary` in two places. What situations could cause multiple copies of the static variable `m_instance` to appear?

- In the case of diamond pattern, would this lead to two of the singleton?:

```
             app.exe
            /       \
static/shared_lib static/shared_lib
            \       /
    SingletonAndOtherStuff.dll
```

- If I had multiple copies of the exact same dll on disk, would that lead to multiple copies of the singleton?

```
                      app.exe
                     /       \
                    /         \
        static/shared_lib static/shared_lib
                 |                 |
SingletonAndOtherStuff.dll SingletonAndOtherStuff.dll
```

- If there were other combinations or longer chains of `STATIC` and `SHARED` libraries between `app.exe` and `SingletonAndOtherStuff.dll`, could that cause multiple instances of the singleton?

I am just looking for an explanation for what would cause this pattern to fall over in the situation where the dll is loaded twice.

Comment: Pro tip: Just avoid singletons (like the plague). They eventually *always* cause more harm than gain.

Comment: I am aware - It was answers similar to that in other threads that which made me want to ask this question. I'm not really interested in why singletons are bad, or what specific C++ fixes I need to make my specific example work. I am looking for help understanding what happens when linking/loading these dlls to make them fall over.

Comment: "What would cause this pattern to fall over in the situation where the dll is loaded twice" is the fact that the dll is loaded twice. It's the same reason water is wet, and the sky is blue. Each loaded instance of the DLL, apparently, is a standalone bubble of the universe, with all static objects in existence. Two static objects. Two singletons. One massive hairball of confusion. You have a description of a rhinoceros in an encyclopedia. You take two copies of the encyclopedia and put it on your desk. You can now find two identical descriptions of a rhinoceros, in front of you.

Comment: Windows dedupes DLLs by full path. If you copy `SingletonAndOtherStuff.dll` under a different name, or into another directory, then you could load two copies of it, each managing its own singleton instance.

Comment: the diamond pattern will only have 1 instance, mistakenly loading 2 versions of the library (either through 2 dlls with same name, or by linking to 2 dlls that statically link your library) will cause multiple instances to exist.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I was under, the perhaps naïve, impression that one of a dll's advantages was that it could be shared by multiple things without the need for multiple copied to be created?

The example I have given is one app loading the same one dll two times. Should it not just say "ah, I already have this mapped - no need to do so again"?

Comment: @Cascades dlls are "handle" (reference) counted, multiple loads to the same dll on disk will only load it once, you have to have 2 copies of it on disk to be able to load 2 version of the dll, and have 2 singletons.

Comment: Multiple processes, sure, share the code. However, it would be quite hilarious for multiple processes to have shared data, and have a single instance of a singleton to be juggled between them. It would be quite a feat to do that, with virtual memory. Think about it, does that make sense to you? Of course not. Only the unchanged, read-only, code from the DLL gets loaded once. Each DLL load creates a separate copy of whatever data there is in a DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's break this down piece by piece. This dilemma you're facing is quite common among developers when dealing with shared libraries, and the presence of singletons just adds another layer of complexity. Thanks for giving a detailed context; I'll tackle each segment.

1. **Singleton Inside a DLL:**

First off, our singleton pointer, being static, has its place reserved in memory as soon as our DLL is loaded. This space remains unique, ensuring our singleton stays singular if the DLL is only loaded once.

2. **What Happens When a DLL is Loaded More Than Once?:**

Here's the thing: even if you repeatedly call LoadLibrary for the same DLL within the same process, the OS doesn't load it afresh each time. It's smart about it and just ups its internal reference count. This ensures our singleton isn't cloned.

3. **About That Diamond Pattern:**

The pattern you've mapped out:

```
             app.exe
            /       \
static/shared_lib static/shared_lib
            \       /
    SingletonAndOtherStuff.dll
```

Even if both those static/shared libraries beckon the `SingletonAndOtherStuff.dll`, it remains one and the same in memory. So, our buddy `singleton` stays one of a kind.

4. **Dealing With Twin DLLs on Disk**:

Now, consider this setup:

```
                  app.exe
                 /       \
                /         \
    static/shared_lib static/shared_lib
             |                 |
SingletonAndOtherStuff.dll SingletonAndOtherStuff.dll
```

If you've got two identical DLLs, but they're sitting at different addresses on your disk and both get loaded, the OS sees them as distinct entities. This means they each get their own spot in memory, causing our `singleton` to be replicated. Yes, you'd end up with two singletons.

5. **Tangled Webs of Libraries**:

It doesn't matter how convoluted the library chain gets. The key thing? How many times, and from which spots on your disk, the `SingletonAndOtherStuff.dll` gets loaded. Different locations mean different singleton instances.

To wrap up: the singleton behaves as expected when our DLL is invited once from a single spot within one process. But if you're pulling in the same DLL from multiple addresses, even if they're carbon copies, you'll get multiple singletons. It's a quirky aspect of shared libraries, and it's essential to have a grasp on these dynamics when diving into such waters.